# Сомнительные переводы в redact

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора, ревизии

Если открыть страницу с ревизиями, к которым применялась функциональность redact, то показывается такое сообщение:

[image: Скриншот серверной версии]

> отредактировано участником Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica 16ч назад

Тут несколько сомнительных моментов:

- "участником" - должно быть "модератором"
- "отредактировано" - возможно стоит заменить это слово?
- "15ч" - просто некрасиво смотрится
- отступ слева вроде бы лишний

А если немного подождать, чтобы время пересчиталось в браузере, то надпись поменяется:

[image: Скриншот клиентской версии]

> отредактировано участником Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica 16 часов назад

Теперь уже в ней не "15ч", а "15 часов" - надо бы сделать одинаковый формат.

Comment: Появились новые переводы.

Comment: Хм.. Кто и за что минусует вопросы по локализации? о_О

Comment: Может модераторов не любят. Или минусуют за то, что эти локализации видим только мы и не хотят видеть таких постов на мете.

Comment: Или может это твой личный хейтер :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. > "участником" - должно быть "модератором"

   В оригинале там вообще "участника" нет:

   > redacted by $user$ $date$

   Вероятно, было сделано из-за того, что у нас падежи есть.

   Поменял на:

   > отредактировано модератором $user$ $date$
2. > "отредактировано" - возможно стоит заменить это слово?

   На что? "Редакция изменена"? В оригинале там "redacted". Не знаю, что можно ещё по смыслу подобрать.
3. > "15ч" - просто некрасиво смотрится

   Не уверен, что мы что-то тут можем сделать. Там подставляется переменная `$date$` =/
4. > отступ слева вроде бы лишний

   Ага. Странный `margin-left: 20px;` зачем-то. Задал [вопрос на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341198/260198).

Comment: Про формат даты/времени уже встречалось как-то ситуация такая. Когда при загрузке странице одно, а при таймауте уже другое. Так что это общий механизм для многих мест.

Comment: "отредактировано" можно менять на "перезаписано" (ссылка же "переписать правку" названа), "исправлено" или "зачищено". А может и ещё варианты есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy "перезаписано" слух режет прям =/